# how to create a 2 dimensional array of strings using gets in c?

Tags: c

I want to create a 2 dimensional array(for example A[5][1] ) that has a character string in each row. This string should be given as a word from the keyboard using gets.
I want something like :

```
char A[5][1];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
printf("Enter a word:");
gets(A[i][0]);}
```

this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: gets does not exist anymore, and in the past it wasn´t meant to read single chars. Do you know about the \0 at the end of C-strings?

Comment: (a) Don't ever use `gets()`.  As in *never*, **never**, ***never***, ***NEVER*** use `gets()` (even though it exists on most implementations, still, for backwards compatibility, but you should assume it will crash your program).  It is no longer a part of standard C.  It cannot be used safely.  No program using `gets()` can defend itself from abuse at the moment it calls `gets()`. It doubly cannot be used safely with 1-element arrays as in `char A[5][1];`.  You could only store empty lines safely in that array.

Comment: @deviantfan: `gets()` does still exist; it should never be used. It is no longer a part of Standard C, but many implementations still support C99 and even C89 where it was standard -- but it was always a bad idea to use it, even back in the 1980s.  Look up the 'Morris Internet Worm' (suitable Google search term); it used `gets()` as one of its methods of propagating.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You even wrote it yourself ("It is no longer a part of standard C") ?

Comment: @deviantfan: There's a big difference between 'not part of the standard' and 'not available for use' and 'does not exist'.  Lots of things that are not in the C standard are available for use, and `gets()` is one of those.  'Not available for use' might be because the implementation is `char *gets(char *str) { abort(); }` -- it exists, but if you call it, your program will crash.  'Does not exist' means the symbol is not present in the library at all.

Comment: @edit: Of course it´s bad to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a 2D array of character, but you say you want a 2D array of "strings".  Now the term "string" is somewhat ambiguous in C -- it could mean an array of characters holding a string, or it could mean a pointer pointing at some memory holding a null-terminated sequence of characters.

Assuming you want fixed-sized arrays of characters as your strings, you could do this as simply as:

```
#define MAX_STRING    256;

char A[5][1][MAX_STRING];
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    printf("Enter a word:");
    fgets(A[i][0], MAX_STRING, stdin); }
```

Or if you want dynamic strings that can have different lengths, you can do

```
char *A[5][1];
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    char buffer[256];
    printf("Enter a word:");
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
    A[i][0] = strdup(buffer); }
```

Comment: Why keep the array dimension of `[1]`?  It is substantially pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Its completely pointless, but seems to be what the OP wants for some reason -- A 2D array where one of the dimensions is size 1.

Comment: It is a 'for example', propagated into the example.  Were it my answer, I'd probably use `char A[5][MAX_STRING];` for the fixed size arrays, pointing out that the second dimension is the upper limit on the length of the string, and that using 1 for the limit means that only empty strings can be stored, and empty strings are very unexciting.  (I'd also test `if (fgets(...) == 0) break;` so that EOF is handled correctly.)

Comment: Using the first, each row will be a series of characters and then '\0'?

Comment: @user3609317: using either, each row will contain a single string and that string wil have a series of characters followed by `'\0'`